# Matplotlib - How to set Text below other objects when they overlap?

Tags: text, matplotlib

when using matplotlib, how can I set the text to be below other objects, like `Rectangles`, `LineCollections`, etc ? Or more generally, how does matplotlib decide the order the objects will appear when they overlap each other? Unlike with grids, there's no function like `Axes.set_textbelow()` to use, I also googled this subject but got no satisfying result.

Below is the stock chart I draw with matplotlib. Note the volume section, I want to set the notes(white text) to be below the volume bars where they overlap. The notes are Text objects drawn with `Axes.text()`, the volume bars are `LineCollection` objects drawn with `Axes.vlines()`.

[image: stock chart I draw with matplotlib]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for zorder:

```
from pylab import *

fig = figure(1)
fig.clf()
ax = subplot(111)
rect = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((0.2,0.2), 0.3, 0.3, fc = '0.5', ec = '0.0')
ax.add_patch(rect)
ax.text(.4, .4, "Help me, there is a rectangle stuck under me!")

fig = figure(2)
fig.clf()
ax = subplot(111)
rect = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((0.2,0.2), 0.3, 0.3, fc = '0.5', ec = '0.0')
ax.add_patch(rect)
ax.text(.4, .4, "Help me, I'm stuck under a rectangle!", zorder = -1)

show()
```

Comment: It's simple as well as clear. I've tried it and the result looks as good as I was expecting, thanks @Daan !